# incorrectly reading in file

Tags: c++, file-handling

If  I give my program the txt file:

```
BB
MB
150 570 2 
240 570 3 
360 570 0 
FB
E
T
```

It reads it in incorrectly and instead reads it as

```
BB
150 0 0 
240 570 2 
360 570 3 
0 570 0 
MB
FB
E
T
```

Here is a simplified version of what I am using to read this:

```
string one,two,three,four;

ifstream file;
filename+=".txt";//filename is a string
file.open(filename.c_str());

while (file >> one >> two>>three&&one!="MB")
{
//do stuff with it here
}
```

and so on. 
Can someone explain why two and three are initially being set to 0?

Full version of code:

To read:

```
void load(string filename)
{
    string one,two,three,four;

    ifstream file;
    filename+=".txt";
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    //blocks

    //backblock list
    while (file >> one >> two>>three&&one!="MB")
    {
        backBlockList.push_back(
            Block(atoi(two.c_str()),atoi(three.c_str()),atoi(one.c_str())));
    }
    while (file >> one >> two>>three&&one!="FB")
    {
        midBlockList.push_back(
            Block(atoi(two.c_str()),atoi(three.c_str()),atoi(one.c_str())));
    }
    while (file >> one >> two>>three&&one!="E")
    {
        foreBlockList.push_back(
            Block(atoi(two.c_str()),atoi(three.c_str()),atoi(one.c_str())));
    }
    while (file >> one &&one!="T")
    {
        enemyList.push_back(Enemy(atoi(one.c_str())));
        //loads waypoints
        while (file >> one>>two )
        {
            enemyList.at(enemyList.size()-1).addWaypoint(
                atoi(one.c_str()),atoi(two.c_str()));
        }
        while(file>>one>>two>>three>>four)
        {
            textBlockList.push_back(
                TextBlock(atoi(one.c_str()),atoi(two.c_str())));
            textBlockList.at(
                textBlockList.size()-1).setText(three);
            textBlockList.at(
                textBlockList.size()-1).setRange(atoi(four.c_str()));
        }
    }
}
```

To write:

```
void printOut(string filename )
{
    cout<<"printing "<<endl;
    ofstream myfile;
    filename+=".txt";
    myfile.open (filename.c_str());
    myfile << "BB\n";

//prints out blocks
    cout<<"printing backblocks";
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(  i = 0; i<backBlockList.size(); i++)
    {
        backBlockList.at(i).print(myfile);
    }
    cout<<" printed "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"printing midblocks";
    myfile << "MB\n";
    for(  i = 0; i<midBlockList.size(); i++)
    {
        midBlockList.at(i).print(myfile);
    }
    cout<<" printed "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"printing foreblocks";
    myfile << "FB\n";
    for(  i = 0; i<foreBlockList.size(); i++)
    {
        foreBlockList.at(i).print(myfile);
    }
    cout<<" printed "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"printing enemies "<<endl;
    myfile<<"E\n";
    for(  i =0; i<enemyList.size(); i++)
    {
        enemyList.at(i).print(myfile);
    }
    cout<<"printing text";
    myfile<<"T\n";
    for(  i =0; i<textBlockList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(textBlockList.at(i).complete())
            textBlockList.at(i).print(myfile);
    }
    cout<<" printed "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"printing other"<<endl;
//Additional stuff goes here EX BACKGROUND

    myfile.close();
    cout<<"printing done";
}
```

Block write:

```
void Block::print(ofstream & file)
{
    file << x;
    file << " ";
    file<< y;
    file<< " ";
    file<< Type;
    file<< " \n";
}
```

TextBlock write:

```
void TextBlock::print(ofstream & file)
{
    file<< x;
    file<<" ";
    file<< y;
    file<<" ";
    file<< text;
    file<<" ";
    file<<range;
    file<<" \n";
}
```

Enemy write:

```
void Enemy::print(ofstream & file)
{
    file<<type;
    for(unsigned int i =0; i<X.size()-1; i++)
    {
        file<<" ";
        file<<   X.at(i);
        file<<" ";
        file<<   Y.at(i);
    }

    file<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I am saving values in a txt file with one program and then loading them to create objects with another

Comment: Have you heard of serialization , just convert the object to binary form and read it :)

Comment: There is no possible way the string `"0"` could be produced by this code. Show us your actual code, not your simplified version.

Comment: full read/write code posted

Comment: That's a funny way to do it IMO. If your data is well formatted there's no reason to use while loops. It also makes your code dependent on those values. Why not read it based on format. And read @xeon111's comment. [Object Serialization](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/serialization.htm)

Comment: The reason it is in a loop is because there could be a differing number of lines

Comment: That's fine, they still appear differently in the file. So there's a way to "know" if you're reading one of the lines formatted with spaces.

Comment: I don't know if I explained myself well, There are multiple types of values which represent different things- they are seperated by different tags- such as BB. The sample I provided only has one type of data (MB).

Comment: Read it just line by line. You're reading 3 lines, then you check the value of the first line. It's no wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the number triples that you got:

```
150 0 0 
240 570 2 
360 570 3 
0 570 0
```

is following: Your input only gets read from the first loop:

```
while (file >> one >> two>>three&&one!="MB")
```

Like following:

```
Loop | one | two | three | atoi | atoi | atoi
     |     |     |       | one  | two  | three
----------------------------------------------
1    |  BB |  MB |   150 |    0 |    0 |   150
2    | 570 |   2 |   240 |  570 |    2 |   240
3    | 570 |   3 |   360 |  570 |    3 |   360
4    | 570 |   0 |    FB |  570 |    0 |     0
5    | breaks the loop because three can't be read
```

The last three columns in the table are the observed number triples.

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected it to read the file as:

```
BB MB 150
570 2 240
570 3 360
570 0 FB
E T
```

because it's always reading three strings at a go. If you want to always read three strings you may wish to pad your MB and BB indicators with dummy `0`s to read (For example `MB 0 0`).

It may help to realize that

`cin >> a >> b >> c;` is no different from `cin >> a; cin >> b; cin >> c;` when it comes to handling newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
file >> one >> two>>three&&one!="FB"
```

reads three strings from a file instead of one.